# Table range as disconnected interval

Tags: list-manipulation

I wish to evaluate table entries but with the dummy variable taking values in separate intervals. For instance, instead of writing

```
Join[Table[x[u], {u, -1, 0, 0.5}], Table[x[u], {u, 1, 2, 0.5}]]
```

I would like to write something like

```
Table[x[u], u ∈ (-1,0) U (1,2), Δu=0.5 ]
```

Comment: Why not do `Table[x[u], {u, Join[Range[-1, 0, 0.5], Range[1, 2, 0.5]]}]`, then? Or you can do a conditional like `If[condition, x[u], Nothing]` within your `Table[]`.

Comment: I have to say that since Wolfram expanded the kinds of iterators in `Plot`, `NIntegrate`, etc., this question seems natural. It even makes sense if the iterator produces a finite, ordered* set of values to iterate over (*or even a nested `List` structure). That last requirement is a bit difficult. But for instance a `MeshRegion` could be iterated over its `MeshCoordinates`. That said, I can't really imagine anything simpler than J.M.'s `Join` & `Range` — no wasted info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as suggested by JM in comment or you can also do

```
del = 0.5;
Table[Map[f, u], {u, {Range[-1, 0, del], Range[1, 2, del]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can do the same also without `Table` at all.

```
Map[f, Sequence @@@ Join[Range[-1, 0, 0.5], Range[1, 2, 0.5]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am sure there are many other ways to do this. The rule of thumb in Mathematica is that there are at least 10 different ways to do the same thing. So it looks like there will be 7 more ways to do this than given already. Maybe others will show the remaining ways.